# How long is google OAuth consent screen verification?

Tags: oauth, google-api

My Google OAuth consent screen verification does not have any progress from 'Your consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use'.

I'm created an app with Google OAuth (using spreadsheet api).
Because this app use spreadsheet api, this app need to be verified by google.
I created this on 25th June. It's already been more than 10 days.

Is there any way to get information of verification progress from google?
Do I need to pay technical support fee for non technical support like this?

Comment: In an email I received from Google Cloud Platform it was mentioned "Please note that the review process may take up to 6 weeks."

Comment: In my case, it is already 8 weeks without a response... They are forcing us to either drop it or buy a support package to solve this inconvenience.

Comment: is there any update on this question, me too have this issue

Comment: What worked in the end OP?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to check the FAQs here https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#how-long. Also if your verification process is taking longer than the expected I would recommend to contact G Suite API Support, they may be able to help you to speed up the process if your case is applicable for that.

Make sure to check "[How do i get my verification completed faster](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#faster)". Make sure all the information you can send when you submit the verification is as detailed as possible, as a recommendation provide them with a video with a tour about how your application works and what it does.

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same problem.

The one advice we followed was to open an issuetracker ticket.

Here is our ticket:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/300953246

Please upvote the ticket, and add any details there if needed. This may help us to bring attention to the problem.

---

After all we reached the help center and it resolved our issue. We've bought a Standard Support plan, contacted them and got a reply. In a week we've finally received a response email from the Safety team.

Here's the link if you want to also select this option:
https://console.cloud.google.com/support/offerings

Comment: We're in a similar situation (well past the 6 week expected response time). Which support plan (Standard, Enhanced, Premium) did you use to get a resolution?

Comment: Hi @kris-braun, we used a Standard Support

Comment: Interesting. So they are stalling until we buy a support plan. Maybe they should make that clear from the start. We first submitted our own Google Drive project 16 months ago, and there is no approval in sight. They make us go around in circles, asking to explain what has already been explained several times. Laughable.